# Eclipse CDT: How to relink static libraries without Project Clean>>Project Rebuild

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible to rebuild a c++ project in eclipse without recompiling to link the static libraries? I can't find the build settings to allow you to do this...

I'm a bit new to c++. My understanding is that if you have a static library, the .o files are linked at the end. However, on every build, all the .cpp files of the executable needs to be recompiled.

My question is:

> If none of the .cpp files of the exe were modified, but the static
>   library source was modified, is there a way to link the static library
>   to the exe .o files without rebuilding?

Comment: Not familiar with eclipse but what about just deleting the target/executable?

Comment: I made some edits to give some more detail above

Answer (score 1):

Add your static library under the *Linker-Settings->Miscellaneous->Other objects*. Your executable will just be relinked, in case the library is newer. No compilation.